# Change x and y position of a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I would like to change the position of the lineEdit (or even a PushButton if it's not possible with the lineEdit) from my Qt application, according to the input given.
So let's say that I want the x position to be 150 pixels, then I would insert 150 into the lineEdit.
Is there any way to do this?

I've already tried this:

```
void DrawTest::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
    QString x = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << "x: " << x;
    QString style = "QLineEdit {"
                    ":" +ui->lineEdit->text()+ "px;"
                    "background-color: #FF00FF;"
                    "};";
    qDebug() << "Style: " << style;
    ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet(style);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QPushButton alignment on top another widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908521/qpushbutton-alignment-on-top-another-widget)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how the QLineEdit is initially positioned. Is it placed within a layout? If so, you won't be able to place it at an absolute position.

But if it does not belong to any layout, you can just use the `move` method:

```
ui->lineEdit->move(x, y);
```

[Here's the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#move-1).